# How can i create a loop that can add the number to a string. Python

Tags: python

What i want is to make this on python:

```
sta1 = net.addStation( 'sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01', ip='10.0.0.1/8', range='30')

sta2 = net.addStation( 'sta2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.2/8', range='30')
...
sta20 = net.addStation( 'sta0', mac='00:00:00:00:00:20', ip='10.0.0.20/8', range='30')
```

But in a loop so i dont have to write 100 times the line where only the numbers change.

Comment: have you tried writing a for loop in python?

Comment: I never worked before with python and know how to create a loop, but i don't know how to make the number in the variable and name to grown with the loop. I thougth about use an array for the:
    sta[i]=...

Answer (score 3):

Use a format string:

```
for i in range(1,101):
    sta[i] = net.addStation('sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:{:02x}'.format(i), ip='10.0.0.{:d}/8'.format(i), range='30')
```